# MYSQL SHA2 512 with multiple transformations

Tags: mysql, sha2

I have to count SHA2 512 checksum, but there is also requirement of "number of transformations". I can't find any answer. Anyone can help me using MYSQL/MSSQL ? Is it possible at all using those languages?

EDIT: **number of transformations : 5000**

```
SELECT (SHA2( '20191018143572123034102012221314181237774212' , 512));
```

**Recieved:** 
371a4fbf2b393338d0a6c619ec18fe5f636fdc1992c09763acfd5dae0bb97b13359fb091e4a196ba085d1a60a312733d6a384e937e32c9aef7063c7911d46b84

**Expected :** 
f8b915776eab735fdd10266b2e66068447904852b82c30eeb6de30703a087eb17ea4c4a37630494607194ddb9354c1211bd984fb5f4d9cff95f5a24ed52065e7

Comment: What do your requirements state precisely?

Comment: There is only one requirement: **number of transformations:5000**

Comment: They probably want you to hash the hash - 5000 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fill a table with 5000 or more rows.

```
mysql> create table n ( n smallint unsigned auto_increment primary key);
mysql> insert into n (n) select null;
mysql> insert into n (n) select null from n;
... repeat doubling the rows in the table until you have more than 5000 rows ...
```

Set a session variable to your original string.

```
mysql> set @value = '20191018143572123034102012221314181237774212';
```

Set the variable to a hash of itself for each row in a 5000 row set.

```
mysql> select @value := sha2(@value, 512) from n limit 5000;
```

The last row of that query will be the result of hashing 5000 times. You can also query the variable's current value:

```
mysql> select @value;
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @value                                                                                                                           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| f8b915776eab735fdd10266b2e66068447904852b82c30eeb6de30703a087eb17ea4c4a37630494607194ddb9354c1211bd984fb5f4d9cff95f5a24ed52065e7 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Frankly, this is easier in practically any other programming language besides SQL.

You should just use a loop.

You might also want to use a different hashing method that uses key stretching instead of relying on 5000 repetitions of SHA2. Typically, repeating re-hashing that many times is done to make the calculation take longer, to make it less attractive for attackers to try automated password guessers.

You can also just use `SELECT SLEEP(1)` or an equivalent function in your app if you want to add a small delay.